# How to have zero or more arguments to a std::function used as value in a std::map?

Tags: c++, lambda, stdmap, std-function

I have a Engine class which has a member of type std::map, that maps enum to member functions.
I'm able to map the enum to all the functions, if the number of arguments of the functions are same.

```
enum STATE { OFF, ON, HIBERNATE, RESTART };
enum RETCODE { SUCCESS, FAIL, UNKNOWN, OUTOFBOUND };

class Engine
{
    Engine();
    RETCODE StateOn(double val);
    RETCODE StateOff(double val);
    RETCODE StateHibernate(double val);
    RETCODE StateRestart(double val);
private:
    const std::map<STATE, std::function<RETCODE(double)>> Map_State_FnPtr;
};

Engine::Engine() : Map_State_FnPtr {
        { STATE::ON, [=](double val) {return StateOn(val); } },
        { STATE::OFF, [=](double val) {return StateOff(val); } },
        { STATE::HIBERNATE, [=](double val) {return StateHibernate(val); } },
        { STATE::RESTART, [=](double val) {return StateRestart(val); } }
    }
{
    // c'tor body
}
```

But I have a scenario where some of the functions can have zero or multiple arguments.
How do I declare & construct the map variable in such scenario?

```
class Engine
{
    Engine();
    RETCODE StateOn();                                              // No arguments
    RETCODE StateOff(double val);                                   // 1 argument
    RETCODE StateHibernate(double val, const std::string & data);   // Multiple arguments
    RETCODE StateRestart(double val);
private:
    const std::unordered_map<STATE, std::function<RETCODE()>> Map_State_FnPtr; // What should be the declaration?
};
```

Any other suggestions for this scenario?
Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always ignore parameters

```
{
    { STATE::ON, [=](double, const std::string &) {return StateOn(); } },
    { STATE::OFF, [=](double val, const std::string &) {return StateOff(val); } },
    { STATE::HIBERNATE, [=](double val, const std::string & data) {return StateHibernate(val, data); } },
    { STATE::RESTART, [=](double val, const std::string &) {return StateRestart(val); } }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I declare & construct the map variable in such scenario?

This is impossible with `std::function`. This template offers a certain amount of type erasure, as it can be constructed with function pointers, stateful lambdas or pointer to member functions, but there is an invariant, i.e., the signature of the function type that you approximate with the `std::function` instance.

You could instead define a custom aggregate that embodies possible variations of parameter lists, e.g.

```
struct StateParams {
    double val;
    std::string data;
};
```

then change your function signatures to

```
RETCODE StateOn(const StateParams&);
RETCODE StateHibernate(const StateParams&);
// ...
```

and the `std::map` can have a `value_type` `std::function<RETCODE(const StatemParams&>`.

Comment: If not by using std::function, how can I declare/construct a std::map to suit the following requirement. Other alternative suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You could try going with `std::any` and `any_cast` if you have C++17 available, but this requires an additional field to remember the actual signature, and it's also quite unsafe. There is no easy way to do this.